# omnet++ installation error in ubuntu

Tags: omnet++

i am getting the following error while running "make" command.

cd /home/bismillah/Desktop/omnetpp-4.1/out/gcc-release/src/utils && /home/bismillah/Desktop/omnetpp-4.1/src/utils/install-prog opp_lcg32_seedtool /home/bismillah/Desktop/omnetpp-4.1/bin
/bin/sh: /home/bismillah/Desktop/omnetpp-4.1/src/utils/install-prog: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [all] Error 126
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/bismillah/Desktop/omnetpp-4.1/src/utils'
make: *** [utils] Error 2

The configure command worked properly,, kindly help;

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned install-prog script should have an executable flag set on linux.

i.e. use

$ chmod +x install-prog

on it, but usually that should be set automatically once you extract the archive using 
$ tar xvfz omnetdistro-vertsion.tgz

Probably you have extracted the Widnows version with unzip. I would try a reainsall and following closely the INSTALL guide.